# Debugging MiniDump

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, symbols, debug-symbols, postmortem-debugging

I have compiled a Debug-Version of my application in one folder. There are now all dll's, pdb's and the exe with the pdb.
I have now created a MiniDump of my running application started out of this path with Taskmanager. Now, I can open this dmp-File in Visual Studio 2010. But when I try to debug, there will be a message, that the symbols could not be found. I have added the path to my symbols (pdb) to the symbol-paths in visual studio - but with no success. I have also try to load the symbols over the ContextMenu of the modules. It is searching there for `MyApp.pdb` and I have selected the correct pdb. But I get the message `A matching symbol file was not found in this folder`.

What can I do to make post mortem debug of my MiniDump with Visual Studio 2010 (so it will find my symbols)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do your pdb's and dll's have the same timestamp? Are they both recreated when you rebuild?
2. Try using [chkmatch](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html) to ensure your dll and pdb match.

Use chkmatch this way:
 `chkmatch -c MyApp.exe MyApp.dll`

The output should look something like this

> Debug information file:
>   Format: PDB 7.00
>   Signature: {ef4bc52f-0161-4e0a-8654-cc1368d7a8a6}  Age: 1
>
> Result: Matched

You shouldnt need to set the symbol path if your pdb's are in the same location as the exe you are dumping.

Are you on .NET 4?

Comment: @wal - yes they have the same timestamp. chkmatch gives me the result 

Debug information file:
Format: PDB 7.00
Signature: {0c98df34-162a-4fed-ab4a-2f241f7d1ffc}  Age: 1

Result: Matched

Yes, I use .NET 4. 
The application, which I try to debug is a x86-Application. The machine is a x64 Machine with Visual Studio 2010 Premium and Windows 7. Could this be a problem?

Comment: @t.kehl very strange indeed! got the latest VS service packs? Not sure what to suggest now; I have just tried what you are trying with a temporary project and it works ok for me. Do you want to send me what you've got (pdb, dll and dmp files) ?

Comment: @t.kehl If you are debugging an x86 application then you need to use Debugging Tools for Windows to get a 32bit dumpfile. VS should alert you of this when you open the DMP file however

Comment: @wal - Yes, I have the latest ServicePack and I am using .NET 4 (I have written this in the first comment ;-). I can send you my dmp and the starting exe with the pdb. Is this enough, that you can test on your side? I can upload this on my DropBox.

Comment: @t.kehl you need to install the 32bit version of debugging tools for windows. ie, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463016
 and then create a dumpfile using windbg, follow this link: http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Creating_a_Core_Dump_from_a_Running_Process_using_WinDbg

Comment: @wal - thank you. I will try this later and come back here after. ok?

Comment: @wal - I have tried it and created a dump with WinDbg x86. There I will get the fallowing message: (e64.618): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
...

Comment: ... And when I try to debug the dump, I get the follow message in Visual Studio:
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in temp.dmp.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in temp.dmp or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while temp.dmp has focus.


but there are no more information in the outputwindow :-(

Comment: ok, instead of getting the dumpfile like it says to in that link, go to the install folder of debugging tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)) and issue `adplus.exe -crash -pn yourapp.exe -o c:\temp`

Comment: then go and open the DMP file under c:\temp